# Add to current Solution by default when creating a new Project

Tags: visual-studio

By default when creating a project, Visual Studio chooses for us to create a new solution too for the given project. Is there a configurable setting that would set the choice in this [dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9sEq.png)
to be on "Add to Solution" instead of "Create new Solution" by default ?

Comment: Not sure. However, you *can* just right-click on the solution's base-node in the Solution Explorer and select the "Add -> New project" command. That then bypasses that part of the UI.

Comment: @AdrianMole That's a perfect alternative, thanks a lot !